# Efficient serialization of JSON values in MapDB

Tags: json, mapdb

I am using [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org) and want to store JSON values in a `BTreeMap`. As far as I understand, there is no (default) `Serializer` for JSON values. I know I can implement one myself. But because this is probably a very common use case, i wonder if there are some implementations out there.

*Side note*: I tried to implement a `Serializer` for [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) but it was more difficult than expected: MessagePack expects an `OutputStream` for writing the binary format, where MapDB uses a `DataOutput`. Final code was ugly and not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'official' way. Best is probably to use Serializer.STRING.

Comment: So persisting the String representation of the JSON object?